# TLS Recommendations

Tags: ssl, offline

I have a product I would like to sell. This product is broken into two physical devices and follows the client server architecture. One device is the server and the other is the client. I am looking to use TLS to secure connection between the server and client.

I would like to setup a server side TLS. I have done research on how to accomplish this with openssl. My strategy at the moment is as follows

- create a CA cert
- create a Server cert
- sign the server cert with the CA

Here's where I struggle to find a solution. I need to support a solution where the two devices do not have access to the internet.

- how do I share my CA with clients to complete TLS handshake? To my understanding TLS uses third party to authenticate the cert so you would need internet access if i signed my certs with a CA company
- if I share CA with cleint device at production. This works for initial installs but what about once CA cert expires and I need to renew it. Do I just use an API call to get CA from the server. do I have to physically add to the machine every time. Is there any best practices.
- lastly is it bad practice to regenerate the CA cert say every 90 days from a script running on the device running the server.

Comment: `To my understanding TLS uses third party to authenticate the cert so you would need internet access if i signed my certs with a CA company` No. All trusted certificates are stored on your computer.

Comment: @tkausl does CA company push cert down to computer or does computer request for CA. I am trying to figure out how once my custom CA expires how to get new CA cert from the server device

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not so much a programming question as one of key / certificate management, which is better handled by [security.se].

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two devices, and control both, using some kind of shared secret (PSK) between the two devices is likely a lot more convenient and safer that half assing an ersatz PKI. Just make sure it's a different, random, PSK per device pair, and that the owner can actually change them. This is doable with TLS using a PSK suite (see [RFC 5489](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5489.html) for TLS 1.2, [RFC 7905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7905.html) for TLS 1.3), but something like IPsec or Wireguard is also perfectly doable.